# How to Get current selection From Smiley Rating bar?

Tags: android

[Smiley Rating bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZVz8.gif)
Hello,I just getting started with android ,and I am trying to use smiley rating bar,i add it to my project,
my problems is :

1-Get current selection (the choice of the user) i read the instructions on the git,but i didn't understand how can i get the user choice.
2-send that choice or the selection of the user to an email address without opening the email app ( directly send ).

this the git https://github.com/sujithkanna/SmileyRating.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the view from xml in your java class by `smileRatingBar = findViewById(R.id.smile_rating_bar_id);`
then you need to add listener for it:

```
smileRatingBar.setOnSmileySelectionListener(new SmileRating.OnSmileySelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSmileySelected(@BaseRating.Smiley int smiley, boolean reselected) {
                // reselected is false when user selects different smiley that previously selected one
                // true when the same smiley is selected.
                // Except if it first time, then the value will be false.
                switch (smiley) {
                    case SmileRating.BAD:
                        Log.i(TAG, "Bad");
                        break;
                    case SmileRating.GOOD:
                        Log.i(TAG, "Good");
                        break;
                    case SmileRating.GREAT:
                        Log.i(TAG, "Great");
                        break;
                    case SmileRating.OKAY:
                        Log.i(TAG, "Okay");
                        break;
                    case SmileRating.TERRIBLE:
                        Log.i(TAG, "Terrible");
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thats true but how are u solving the email issue?

Comment: From my experience sending email without opening the app is not possible, the only way is to have server which will be able to do that and when you get the rating from user send post request to your server and it will take care to send the email.

Comment: my problem is how can i Get current selection
in the instructions he say use this
@Smiley int smiley = mSmileRating.getSelectedSmile();
switch (smiley) {
    case SmileRating.BAD:
        Log.i(TAG, "Bad");
        break;
    case SmileRating.GOOD:
        Log.i(TAG, "Good");
        break;
    case SmileRating.GREAT:
        Log.i(TAG, "Great");
        break;
    case SmileRating.OKAY:
        Log.i(TAG, "Okay");
        break;
    case SmileRating.TERRIBLE:
        Log.i(TAG, "Terrible");
        break;
    case SmileyRating.NONE:
     Log.i(TAG, "None");
     break;
}

Comment: each case is the choice

Comment: but how can i use this method  getSelectedSmile() to get back what the user choose

Comment: int smiley is user's selection, from here you can do whatever you want with this selection.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query i.e. how to know the current selection (the choice of the user) can be known by the following way :

```
SmileRating smileRating = findViewById(R.id.feedback_rating);
int level = smileRating.getRating();
```

Where Level will return 0 if NONE selected else will return 1 to 5 ranging where 1 is Terrible while 5 is Great.